# How to collect different data from array or hash by ruby language?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

For example,I have datas:

```
a,b,c,a,c,d
```

- I want to get different datas: a,b,c,d
- I want to get data count: a => 2,b => 1,c => 2,d => 1

There may have other datas,such as e,f,g,etc.

How to do?

Comment: You should take a stab at it first. Read docs, write code, etc. Questions like this ("here are the requirements, go ahead and write the code for me") are quite discouraged here. We love to help, but we also don't like wasting time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = [:a,:b,:c,:a,:c,:d]
p h = a.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)){|i,h| h[i] += 1}
p h.keys
# >> {:a=>2, :b=>1, :c=>2, :d=>1}
# >> [:a, :b, :c, :d]
```